# GTest (cci.20210126) does not find overloaded << operator on Linux GCC 9

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm currently having some trouble on upgrading to latest GTest from Conan Center (at the time of writing this is GTest cci.20210126). My Code worked fine with old GTest V1.10.

In our project we use the << Operator to convert Data to a string stream and vice versa

```
class Foo;

/* overloading of << operator */
std::ostream&  operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, Foo const& rhs);
/* overloading of >> operator */
std::istream&  operator>>(std::istream& lhs, Foo& rhs);


class Foo
{
public:
  // overloading of << operator
  friend std::ostream&  ::operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, Foo const& rhs);
  // overloading of >> operator
  friend std::istream&  ::operator>>(std::istream& lhs, Foo& rhs);
}
```

I get lots of

```
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:108:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Foo’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&)’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)’}
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:117:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]’
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
```

=>this sound like modern GTest does not find the << operator overload

What is the modern way to overload the operator? I personally am not so keen of using the friends keyword extensively

Could you help me out here?

**Edit:**
As requested the full (very long) error message. I'm sorry I don't know where to clip it

```
[13/275] Building CXX object x/x/core/datatypes/tests/CMakeFiles/UnitTest_ProbeValue.dir/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp.o
FAILED: x/x/core/datatypes/tests/CMakeFiles/UnitTest_ProbeValue.dir/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/c++ -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DTIXML_USE_STL -DprojCOVERAGE_TEST=0 -I/home/user/.vs/build/y/_t300_linux_ninja/x/x -I/home/user/.vs/build/y/_t300_linux_ninja/x -I/home/user/.vs/y/x -isystem /home/user/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/include -isystem /home/user/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore -isystem /home/user/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/./mkspecs/linux-g++ -isystem /home/user/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui -isystem /home/user/.conan/data/tinyxml/2.6.2/_/_/package/344b57466ca5410afe53b08a52efb92ca37883f2/include -isystem /home/user/.conan/data/jsoncpp/1.9.4/_/_/package/a0d04ca949f5f2ad68af2af705b4e0f9a95967a0/include -isystem /home/user/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/_/_/package/23b828d52c0630e6b0b96d2945419feb7843c4f8/include -isystem /home/user/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-error=strict-overflow -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-conversion-null -Wno-error=comment -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-error=strict-overflow -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-conversion-null -Wno-error=comment -gdwarf-2 -fpermissive -fdiagnostics-generate-patch -g -fPIC -std=c++2a -MD -MT x/x/core/datatypes/tests/CMakeFiles/UnitTest_ProbeValue.dir/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp.o -MF x/x/core/datatypes/tests/CMakeFiles/UnitTest_ProbeValue.dir/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp.o.d -o x/x/core/datatypes/tests/CMakeFiles/UnitTest_ProbeValue.dir/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp.o -c /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/tests/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp
In file included from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:48,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h:39,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h:41,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest.h:64,
                 from /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/tests/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp:3:
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h: In instantiation of ‘struct testing::internal::FindFirstPrinter<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >, void, testing::internal::internal_stream_operator_without_lexical_name_lookup::StreamPrinter, testing::internal::ProtobufPrinter, testing::internal::ConvertibleToIntegerPrinter, testing::internal::ConvertibleToStringViewPrinter, testing::internal::RawBytesPrinter, testing::internal::FallbackPrinter>’:
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:287:8:   required from ‘struct testing::internal::FindFirstPrinter<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >, void, testing::internal::ContainerPrinter, testing::internal::FunctionPointerPrinter, testing::internal::PointerPrinter, testing::internal::internal_stream_operator_without_lexical_name_lookup::StreamPrinter, testing::internal::ProtobufPrinter, testing::internal::ConvertibleToIntegerPrinter, testing::internal::ConvertibleToStringViewPrinter, testing::internal::RawBytesPrinter, testing::internal::FallbackPrinter>’
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:307:9:   required from ‘void testing::internal::PrintWithFallback(const T&, std::ostream*) [with T = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:441:30:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:902:30:   required from ‘void testing::internal::UniversalPrint(const T&, std::ostream*) [with T = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:830:19:   required from ‘static void testing::internal::UniversalTersePrinter<T>::Print(const T&, std::ostream*) [with T = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:940:44:   required from ‘std::string testing::PrintToString(const T&) [with T = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:334:36:   required from ‘static std::string testing::internal::FormatForComparison<ToPrint, OtherOperand>::Format(const ToPrint&) [with ToPrint = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >; OtherOperand = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:415:45:   required from ‘std::string testing::internal::FormatForComparisonFailureMessage(const T1&, const T2&) [with T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >; T2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest.h:1600:63:   required from ‘testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperOpFailure(const char*, const char*, const T1&, const T2&, const char*) [with T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >; T2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >]’
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest.h:1624:1:   required from ‘testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperNE(const char*, const char*, const T1&, const T2&) [with T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >; T2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >]’
/home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/tests/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp:32:3:   required from here
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:291:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘testing::internal::internal_stream_operator_without_lexical_name_lookup::StreamPrinter::PrintValue(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >&, std::nullptr_t)’
  291 |     T, decltype(Printer::PrintValue(std::declval<const T&>(), nullptr)),
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:212:15: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, class, class> static void testing::internal::internal_stream_operator_without_lexical_name_lookup::StreamPrinter::PrintValue(const T&, std::ostream*)’
  212 |   static void PrintValue(const T& value, ::std::ostream* os) {
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:212:15: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:211:33: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’)
  210 |             typename = decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>()
      |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  211 |                                 << std::declval<const T&>())>
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/sstream:38,
                 ...
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:108:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:108:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&)’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)’}
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:117:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]’
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:117:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type&)’ {aka ‘std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)’}
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:127:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  127 |       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:127:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)’
  127 |       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:166:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  166 |       operator<<(long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:166:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘long int’
  166 |       operator<<(long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:170:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  170 |       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:170:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘long unsigned int’
  170 |       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:174:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  174 |       operator<<(bool __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:174:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘bool’
  174 |       operator<<(bool __n)
      |                  ~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:702,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/sstream:38,
                 ...
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:91:5: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
   91 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:92:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘short int’
   92 |     operator<<(short __n)
      |                ~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/sstream:38,
                 ...
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:181:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  181 |       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:181:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘short unsigned int’
  181 |       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:702,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/sstream:38,
                 ...
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:105:5: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
  105 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:106:20: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘int’
  106 |     operator<<(int __n)
      |                ~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/sstream:38,
                 ...
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:192:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  192 |       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:192:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘unsigned int’
  192 |       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:201:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  201 |       operator<<(long long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:201:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘long long int’
  201 |       operator<<(long long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:205:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  205 |       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:205:37: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘long long unsigned int’
  205 |       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:220:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  220 |       operator<<(double __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:220:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘double’
  220 |       operator<<(double __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:224:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  224 |       operator<<(float __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:224:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘float’
  224 |       operator<<(float __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:232:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  232 |       operator<<(long double __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:232:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘long double’
  232 |       operator<<(long double __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:245:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  245 |       operator<<(const void* __p)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:245:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘const void*’
  245 |       operator<<(const void* __p)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:250:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::nullptr_t) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]’
  250 |       operator<<(nullptr_t)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:250:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
  250 |       operator<<(nullptr_t)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:702,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/sstream:38,
                 from /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/exception/TException.h:29,
                 from /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/TypeObject.h:5,
                 from /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/MarkedFloat.h:6,
                 from /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/ProbeValue.h:6,
                 from /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/tests/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:119:5: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]’
  119 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:120:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__streambuf_type*’ {aka ‘std::basic_streambuf<char>*’}
  120 |     operator<<(__streambuf_type* __sbin)
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /home/user/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:65,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest.h:62,
                 from /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/tests/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp:3:
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-message.h:199:22: note: candidate: ‘std::ostream& testing::operator<<(std::ostream&, const testing::Message&)’
  199 | inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Message& sb) {
      |                      ^~~~~~~~
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-message.h:199:67: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘const testing::Message&’
  199 | inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Message& sb) {
      |                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /home/user/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h:39,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h:41,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest.h:64,
                 from /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/tests/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp:3:
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:618:15: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> std::ostream& testing::operator<<(std::ostream&, const testing::Matcher<T>&)’
  618 | std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matcher<T>& matcher) {
      |               ^~~~~~~~
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:618:15: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:48,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h:39,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h:41,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest.h:64,
                 from /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/tests/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp:3:
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:211:33: note:   ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ is not derived from ‘const testing::Matcher<T>’
  210 |             typename = decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>()
      |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  211 |                                 << std::declval<const T&>())>
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/user/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h:52,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest-param-test.h:179,
                 from /home/user/include/gtest/gtest.h:67,
                 from /home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/tests/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp:3:
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-test-part.h:123:15: note: candidate: ‘std::ostream& testing::operator<<(std::ostream&, const testing::TestPartResult&)’
  123 | std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TestPartResult& result);
      |               ^~~~~~~~
/home/user/include/gtest/gtest-test-part.h:123:66: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<z::ProbeValue*, std::vector<z::ProbeValue> >’ to ‘const testing::TestPartResult&’
  123 | std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TestPartResult& result);
      |                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~


ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

**Edit 2:**
After a very good spot from Marek, here are the appropriote code lines

```
TEST(ProbeValueTest, stl_find)
{
  auto testValues{std::vector<ProbeValue>{
      ProbeValue(0.0f, 2U, 0U)
    }};
  auto itr{std::find(testValues.begin(), testValues.end(), ProbeValue(0.0f, 2U, 0U))};
  ASSERT_NE( testValues.end(), itr);
}
```

Comment: This could be an ADL issue.  Try putting your class and the overloaded operators inside the same namespace and see if the removes the error.

Comment: "What is the modern way to overload the operator? I personally am not so keen of using the friends keyword extensively" Sutter https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/20/gotw-4-class-mechanics/, suggested to add to your class this public method: std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const. So, you can implement the operator<< without the friend declaration something like: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& toPrint) { return toPrint.print(os); }

Comment: Please provide [mcve] you can start with [this link](https://godbolt.org/z/M1vYWd).

Comment: Anyway you have clipped error message to much. Those logs cover only standard library lines. There should be more: covering gtest and your code. Copy paste lots of more. Starting from one line before first error massage to the end (of message if you can spot it).

Comment: Take a look on [releases notes](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases) there is `Output` paragraph. It is possible that new features introduced are in conflict with your overloads of `operator>>`.

Comment: Hey guys, I tried to give you a minimum reproducible example but I failed to isolate the issue (I know it would be a lot easier with a nailed down issue) Nathan: I moved the operators into my custom namespace unfortunately this results in the same errors. Alessandro: Good Idea! I'll change that! Marek unfortunately there is nothing related in the release notes. I added the full (very long) error in my first post.  It would be nice if some of you can have a look ;)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to print an iterator. This normally should not work. The error message references a line in your code `/home/user/.vs/y/x/x/core/datatypes/tests/UnitTest_ProbeValue.cpp:32:3`, you should show at least code at and around this line.

Comment: wow thx that was really helpful! I added the code Lines above. Wenn I replace ```ASSERT_NE( testValues.end(), itr);``` with ```ASSERT_FALSE( testValues.end()== itr);``` it works. Does anybody have an idea why ASSERT_NE() and ASSERT_FALSE() behave this differently?

Comment: `ASSERT_NE` wants to print values that failed to compare equal.